# Angular Pikaday configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, pikaday

I tried to implement A[ngular Pikaday](https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular) to my project, however, i cannot set options of the Pikaday directive. I don't what to implement it globally, especially for `minDate` or `maxDate` options. When i try with getting the element by ID it works fine.

I would like to know what i am missing.

```
$scope.myPickerObject = {
    firstDay: 1, // not showing
    numberOfMonths: 2, // not showing
    onSelect: function() {
      alert('hi');
    }

  };
     //$scope.myPickerObject = new Pikaday({   //  onSelect: function() {   //    alert('hi');   //  }   //  Doesn't work either   //});/
```

[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMorshupLfabAh2JqoCv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing pickaday a callback, you should define `on-select` method on input itself like shown in the

**Fiddle:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/X10a4peeKQK2uj30mJQk?p=preview

If you want to configure specific input

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated my question. I changed to display of months to two, still doesn't work either.

Comment: see updated fiddle, you should get the pickaday provided and use setConfig method of that provider

Comment: I don't what do it globally for `minDate`. What is your suqqestion in this case?

Comment: then you should make configuration all inline. In which case numberOfMonths becomes number-of-months and so on...See updated fiddle

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/W4gtUtimdwHDVwq05NuL?p=preview It doesn't get the default date.

Comment: `toLocaleDateString()` that part what i am missing. Thanks :)